# How to close humidity sensor at specific humidity

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, buzzer

[image]I am using dht humidity and temperature sensor on arduino and i would like to add relay and buzzer on the system. What I would like to do is to close it via buzzer and on 65% humidity run buzzer. The code i use is:

```
/* DHT-22 sensor with 12c 16x2 LCD with Arduino uno
   Temperature and humidity sensor displayed in LCD
   based on: http://www.ardumotive.com/how-to-use-dht-22-sensor-en.html and
   https://www.ardumotive.com/i2clcden.html for the i2c LCD library by Michalis Vasilakis
   Recompile by adhitadhitadhit
   Notes: use LCD i2c Library from link above, i'm not sure why but new Liquidcristal library from Francisco Malpartida  isn't working for me
   other thing, check your */

//Libraries
#include <dht.h> // sensor library using lib from https://www.ardumotive.com/how-to-use-dht-22-sensor-en.html
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // LCD library using from  https://www.ardumotive.com/i2clcden.html for the i2c LCD library 
#include <Wire.h> 
dht DHT;

//Constants
#define DHT22_PIN 2     // DHT 22  (AM2302) - pin used for DHT22 
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 after finding it from serial monitor (see comment above) for a 16 chars and 2 line display

//Variables
float hum;  //Stores humidity value
float temp; //Stores temperature value

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    int chk = DHT.read22(DHT22_PIN);
    //Read data and store it to variables hum and temp
    hum = DHT.humidity;
    temp= DHT.temperature;
    //Print temp and humidity values to LCD
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Humidity: ");
    lcd.print(hum);
    lcd.print("%");
    if (humidity <= 50) 
{ 
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
   digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH); 

 } 

 else 

 { 

 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Temp: "); 
    lcd.print(temp);
    lcd.println("Celcius");
    delay(2000); //Delay 2 sec between temperature/humidity check.
}
```

How to add relay and buzzer to close it with buzzer run on 65% humidity value?

Comment: Do you know how to implement the required subtasks (control relay/buzzer, compare values)? If yes, where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: Yes i did it once but this time i changed my LCD connection with socket. Defining buzzer and relay it gives error on ide. I have follewed arduino official code. So i need to adapt it to above code which provides humidity and temperature on LCD

Comment: Hmm, we need to see the code that *doesn't* work and which you have problems with... how do you actually "define" a relay/buzzer? You just need to set the desired pins to outputs and control them with `digitalWrite()` and `tone()` corresponding to some logic you have to implement. Without seeing what you do we can't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: you don't have any code that says `if humidity is equal to 65%, then sound a buzzer`

Comment: I would also suggest you include your schematic, not a fuzzy drawing, that will help a lot.

Comment: For ther buzzer I have added if (humidity <= 50) {

digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH); }

else {

digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW); } But it provides error.  My connection is as follow: LCD: SCL to A5
CDA to A4
GND to GND
VCC to 5V

DHT Data to D2 
VCC to 5V
GND to GND

Buzzer: Data to 7
GND to GND

Comment: A) edit the code in the question instead of posting snippets in comments. B) which error?! C) though it's probably not related to hardware, if you want to inform us about your circuit you should draw *circuit diagram*.

Comment: I have uploaded the infos you asked for. I couldn't decide the relay connection so I need your help on relay connection and code.

Comment: Is it a relay module or a standalone relay?

Comment: It is external 12V relay. I will feed it seperately out of arduino. What I want is to run the buzzer at 65% humidity and close the system via relay around 80% huımidity. I know that I didn't add relay code and buzzer library because that side is completely the part I need the halp.

Comment: `ledPin` and `buzzer` are neither declared/defined, nor are the corresponding pins configured as outputs. I assume the black dot in the drawing is the buzzer. The problem here is that you must not connect the buzzer between Vin (connected to 9V battery) and a GPIO - **this will fry the arduino!** What kind of buzzer is it (datasheet)?

Comment: Did you actually google for "arduino buzzer"/"arduino relay"? There are tons of tutorials out there... those also show you how to wire everything up

Comment: https://components101.com/misc/buzzer-pinout-working-datasheet

Comment: yes I did. But it didn't work. As I mentioned I did the same system once before but I wouldn't use IC12 LCD and It corrupted everything :)

Comment: Normally I am python developer and I haven't been using C# for years. It seems totlly bunk to me at tyhe moment.

Comment: yes I googled it BTW. I have problem where i should add the buzzer and relay lines.

Comment: Currently I am able to show temperature and humidity values on LCD. Other sides I corrupted.

Comment: Can you recommend your solution on draft and code if possible?

Comment: Consider upgrading your power supply, a 9V battery will not cut it. Also a Schematic would be a big help, the frizzy thing is difficult to interpret. You can get KiCad free but it is nice to leave a donation.

Comment: yes I am using external 12V adapter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
void loop()
{
   sample temp and humidity;
   display temp;
   display humidity;

   if humidity <= 50
      LED on;
      buzzer on;
   else
      display temp
      wait 2 sec
   end
```

- There is a missing '}' to to close the if/else.
- Why do you display temp twice within the loop?
- Where is the logic for the relay and the buzzer at 65%?
- Pin numbers for the LED and the buzzer are undefined.
- The LED and buzzer pins need to be set to OUTPUT mode in your setup() function.

If I understand your description, you probably need somethng like the following, in your loop function:

```
   if humidity <= 50
      LED on;
      buzzer on;
   else if hum >= 65%m
      close relay;
      buzzer on;
   end
```

When I have a problem with program logic that isn't obvious to me, I write it out in pseudo-code as I did above. Once I figure out the logic, then I'll type in C++ with proper syntax.
If I haven't understood your intentions in the above pseudo-code, I'd suggest you do the same thing, until you believe what you've written. Only then try to make it into working code.

Comment: What I missed was seems to be added humidity function into void main function. By checking c# I solved it. Now the system works fine thank you.